# jquery missing on wp-admin - wordpress

Tags: jquery, wordpress, wp-admin

I have problem with missing files of jquery in wp-admin. On live site everything is correct, 0 bugs but on wp-admin like you see it's messing jquery file. Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: jQuery isn't linked, or is linked after you try to use it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there is a plugin which causes the problem. Try to deactivate them one by one, if it solves the issue. Try changing the theme, there might be the problem.
If this does not help:

You can try to add jQuery to your backend by hand using `admin_enqueue_scripts` and putting this in the function.php file of your theme:

```
function my_jquery_script() {

    wp_enqueue_script( 'jQuery', 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js');

}    
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'my_jquery_script' );
```

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/admin_enqueue_scripts/

Comment: I deactivated all plugins , I changed theme to default I also add to the start of my function.php file admin_enqueue_scripts and I still has errors with jQuery....

Comment: @pwo please, how did you finally fixed that issue?

Answer (score 0):

FYI:

The only way that strange issue was fixed is when I forcefully loaded a copy of jQuery from a CDN directly inside /public_html/wp-admin/includes/admin.php

```
echo '<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

';

Not sure where that issue comes from, not sure I care, it's WP...
Enjoy -

Comment: Although even there jQuery is not recognized as the jQuery version from the CDN uses $ but hey who cares.  Works for me.